# Return BadRequest to IHttpActionResult Post function from called function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I have a function called in my Post IHttpActionResult function return BadRequest without having to return my function as IHttpActionResult? Say I have the following function:

```
// POST api/Country
[ResponseType(typeof(CountryRegion))]
public IHttpActionResult PostCountryRegion(CountryRegion countryregion)
{
    countryregion = checkAndChangeSomeStuff(countryregion);

    db.CountryRegions.Add(countryregion);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = countryregion.ID }, countryregion);
}
```

rather the default:

```
// POST api/Country
[ResponseType(typeof(CountryRegion))]
public IHttpActionResult PostCountryRegion(CountryRegion countryregion)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.CountryRegions.Add(countryregion);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = countryregion.ID }, countryregion);
}
```

and I want checkAndChangeSomeStuff() to be something like this:

```
protected internal CountryRegion checkAndChangeSomeStuff(CountryRegion countryregion)
{
    //do stuff

    //check stuff
    //somethings wrong
    return BadRequest("CountryCriteria specified does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return BadRequest from your method with CountryRegion returning type. But you can raise an HttpResponseException with BadRequest status code like this:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
  ReasonPhrase = "CountryCriteria specified does not exist"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I undesrtand you correct but you can do this way:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSets(Sets sets)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                try
                {
                    if (ItemExist(sets.SetID, sets.ItemName) == false)
                    {
                        db.Sets.Add(sets);
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
//Here you return HttpResponseException
                        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                        resp.Content = new StringContent("Такой продукт уже добавлен.");
                        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
                    }
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return CreatedAtRoute("PreppApi", new { id = sets.Id }, sets);
            }
```